# What does “instant rotten words” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Does the saying "“instant rotten words”" exist? I Googled it, but I haven't found the match result.

I  watched a video titled, *[Mandarin Interpreter Charles Qin ...](https://youtu.be/6eGCaMk-hXI?t=418)* , and the  Chinese interpreter recommended it. I'm curious about it.

He gave a certain explanation in the video, the phrase seemed to be a term, but I can't find related stuff by Google, so I posted this question.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Without further context, it is almost impossible to say.

Comment: Do you want to say: "Words that become instantly rotten" ? You asked "is this **a** saying?" Do you mean if it is an English idiom, an adage or proverb? The answer to that question is no. Are you translating from your mother tongue? Did you read this phrase somewhere? Please include a link! :)

Comment: OK , I  updated it.

Comment: The youtube video: it's not _instant rotten words_, it's _instant working words_, as I hear it.  These are words learned in preparation, it seems, for a specific conference, perhaps about a specific topic.

Comment: @Xanne The subtitles say "rotten" and the audio quality is not exactly pristine, so it's difficult to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression ***instant rotten words*** was created [ad hoc](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ad-hoc) by the Chinese interpreter in the video. He uses it to explain that many English slang terms on the Internet become **[out of date](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of-date)**  (*rotten*) before the year is over (instant).

The expression is not  typical heard in English  but once  the context is established, it is comprehensible.

[Ten examples](http://www.smosh.com/smosh-pit/articles/short-lived-slang-terms-2000s) of **[outdated](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/outdated)** / **[short-lived](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/short-lived)** slang terms from the 2000s (according to Erika Heidewald)

> Sometimes words start off as slang and become part of everyday language — "awesome", "cool", and "what's up" are all now commonplace. **Some slang words, though, disappear as quickly as they came, to be used only ironically or by people who don't know better.** 2000-2009 was a weird time for pop culture, not as straight-up dorky as the '90s and not as hipster as the '10s. Most of the short-lived slang words of the early '00s are thanks to Snoop Dogg, Lil' Jon, and Three 6 Mafia and they deserve to be respected, remembered, and put to rest.
>
> 1. Fo shizzle
> 2. Fo sheezy
> 3. Crunk
> 4. Cray-cray
> 5. Pimp juice
> 6. Skrill/skrilla
> 7. Peeps
> 8. Head bussa
> 9. Flossy
> 10. Drop it like it's hot

The following [link](http://www.inthe90s.com/generated/terms.shtml) contain outdated 90's phrases, I've heard most of these, so that's showing how *hip* I am. Not. :)